# Equivalent definitions for Hermitian metric on dual line bundle

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a holomorphic line bundle $L$ over complex manifold $X$, suppose $L$ is globally generated by sections $s_1,...,s_k\in H^0(X,L)$, i.e. For any $ x\in X$, not all $s_i(x) $ are $0$. Then there is a natural hermitian metric on $L$ locally defined by $h(t) =\frac{|\psi(t)|^2}{\sum |\psi(s_i(x) |^2} $ for any local trivialization $\psi$ and any $t\in L(x)$.

We can then define $h^*$ on $L^*$, by taking $h^*(\xi) =h(v_{\xi} ) $ where $v_{\xi} \in L$ is defined by $\xi(t) =h(t, v_{\xi} ) $. On the other hand we have natural inclusion $L^*\subset \mathcal O^{\oplus k} $ by $\xi\mapsto (x, \xi(s_1(x)),...,\xi(s_k(x)))$ where $\xi\in L^*(x)$. By taking the standard hermitian metric on the trivial bundle, denote the induced metric by $h'$. Specifically $h'(\xi) =\sum |\xi(s_i(x)) |^2$.

I wish to show that $h^*$ and $h'$ are in fact the same metric. So I have to prove that $$h'(\xi) =\sum |\xi(s_i(x)) |^2=h(v_{\xi}, v_{\xi} )=\xi(v_{\xi}) =h^*(\xi)$$

I speculated that $v_{\xi} =\sum\overline{\xi(s_i(x))} s_i(x)$, but I am not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to compare their hermitian matrix.

By abuse of language,we say that $h$ is given by $(\sum {|s_i|^2})^{-1}$.Then we have $h^*$ is given by $(\sum {|s_i|^2})$.Since $h'(\xi) =\sum |\xi(s_i(x)) |^2$,$h'$ is also given by $(\sum {|s_i|^2})$.Hence we get $h'=h^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to see that $h^*$ is given by the inverse? It does not seem to be independent on local trivialization.

Comment: See: https://mathsoc.jp/publication/PublMSJ/PDF/Vol15.pdf   ,P17 last paragraph to P18.Yes,it is dependent on local trivialization.But now,we should choose a local frame in advance and verify the claim.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it makes perfect sense to consider the inverse matrix. However I think saying that $h^*$ is given by $(\sum |s_i|^2)$ is a bit imprecise, because $s_i$ are not sections of $L^*$. It is probably better to say that locally $h^*$ is given by the inverse $\frac{\sum|\psi(s_i)|^2}{|\psi(t)|^2}$ for local nonvanishing section $t$. But with respect to dual section $t^*$, we have $h'(at^*) =|a|^2 h'(t^*) =|a|^2 \sum |t^*(s_i)|^2=|a|^2\sum |h(s_i, t)|^2=|a|^2 h(t) = h(at)$ which has the same matrix as $h$, wouldn't this be a contradiction?

Comment: Looking at it again, I finally realized my mistake. $t^*$ should be taken as the vector in dual basis $\{t\}$ which satisfies $t^*(t) =1$ but not defined by the hermitian metric. Hence $t^*(s_i)=\frac{|\psi(s_i) |^2}{|\psi(t)|^2}$ and hence $h' = h^*$ as claimed. Thanks again.

Comment: Right!You're welcome!